# Windows 8 - associate regsvr32 with dll type and always run as administrator

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, dll, regsvr32

I'm using Windows 8. I'd like to associate the file type DLL to regsvr32, so that I can double click a DLL and register it. The problem is that regsvr32 is not running as administrator. So, what I need is when I double click a DLL it runs regsvr32 as administrator automatically . Any sugestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: IMO this sort of association is not a great idea.

Comment: @Karan Why do you think so? I've never had problems with that.

Comment: I'm no security expert, but somehow enabling regsvr32 to be run as admin automatically and allowing just any DLL to be registered with elevated rights doesn't sound too secure to me.

Comment: Maybe that's the reason I can't find a way to do that :) Thanks for your comment